# Unable to retrieve the row value?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, tableadapter

I'm using TableAdapters to establish a connection and query through my database tables. I have this query:

```
SELECT salt FROM users WHERE (username = @usernameOrEmail) OR (email = @usernameOrEmail)
```

Which you can imagine since the username and email fields are unique it can only retrieve 1 row, the row can either be NULL or can actually contain a salt depending if the usernameOrEmail parameter has a string matching any username or email.

I use this code to call the query and pass the parameter through:

```
public void checkEmailOrUsername(string emailOrUsername)
{
    DataTable userDataTable = userInfoTableAdapters.getUserSalt(emailOrUsername);
    DataRow userDataRow = userDataTable.Rows[0];
    string saltValue = userDataRow["salt"].ToString();
}
```

It works perfectly when the parameter doesn't match a username or email within the table however breaks when the email or username does matches. It gives an error on this line:

```
DataTable userDataTable = userInfoTableAdapters.getUserSalt(emailOrUsername);
```

And this is the error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.ConstraintException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

Comment: Do you have null values being returned for any columns not set to allow null in your TA?

Comment: The SALT column is NOT NULL @DavidG

Comment: Can you post your GetUserSalt Method? Maybe there is a error in your method of filling the DT, etc.

Comment: Can you do DataTable UserDataTAble = new DataTable(); then UserDataTable = userinfoTableAdapters.GetUserSalt(emailorUsername).
Make sure you initialize your DataTable with new DataTable() in the GetUserSalt method too.

Answer (score 0):

It's not *necessarily* going to return a single salt. Consider the following two accounts:

> Username: john.smith, Email: John.Smith@Email.com
>
> Username: John.Smith@Email.com, Email: JohnSmith2@Email.com

Your query will return both rows. It's something to check first, if that doesn't solve it could you post the content of userInfoTableAdapters.getUserSalt(emailOrUsername) as well as the stack trace?

Comment: I forgot to mention, a username cannot contain @ symbols or dots. I have validated both client and server side to not allow such characters being stored as username. The username only supports letters,numbers,hyphens and underscores